# Getting an error message when Create Procedure code is added to existing code?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that selects all Yogurts with the word 'orange' in their description from a database.

However, although I can run the code to extract all Yogurts with the word 'orange' in their description (see below), when I add the code to create a stored procedure to run this (also below), I get an error message that says

> Incorrect syntax near 'go'

and when you hover over the "create procedure" text it says

> Incorrect syntax: CREATE PROCEDURE must be the only statement in the batch.

Does anyone know why this is? TIA.

```
select * 
from v_EnterpriseStructure as es    
where ProductName like '%orange%' 
  and SubCategoryName = 'Yogurt'
```

Stored procedure code:

```
create procedure OrangeYogurts 
as 
    select * 
    from v_EnterpriseStructure as es    
    where ProductName like '%orange%' 
      and SubCategoryName = 'Yogurt'
go;
```

Comment: `GO` isn't a T-SQL command, it's a script command understood by SSMS and sqlcmd. Just remove it

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks Panagiotis! Removing GO made it work! I'd modified an example I got from w3schools where they had the word GO, but you were right about removing it! Thank you! If you want to add it as an answer below, I'm happy to 'up vote' it!

Comment: P.S I still get a message that says "Incorrect syntax: CREATE PROCEDURE must be the only statement in the batch" when I hover over the 'create procedure' text, even though the command works when GO is removed....

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
create procedure OrangeYogurts 
as 
BEGIN

     select * from v_EnterpriseStructure as es   
     where ProductName like '%orange%' 
    and SubCategoryName = 'Yogurt'
END
```

Comment: Thanks Thilina - removing the word GO from my original code made the code work, as suggested by Panagiotis above. But I tested your code as well, and it worked. Thanks